ruby 3.1.2 how to reference an object property as a method parameter
This may be trivial. I want to reference an object property from within an object method parameter list, if that makes sense.
Trivial example:
'tags'.ljust([calculated_length, obj.length].max)

where, in this example, obj refers to the string tags.
Is this even possible?


reference an object property from within an object method parameter list

Although you are within the method's arguments, you're still outside the object's scope. Ruby doesn't provide a reference to the object at that point.
If you want to refer to the same object multiple times, you'd usually just assign it to a variable:
str = 'tags'
str.ljust([8, str.length].max)
#=> "tags    "

If you don't want to do that, there's yield_self which yields the receiver to the given block and returns the block's result:
'tags'.yield_self { |str| str.ljust([8, str.length].max) }
#=> "tags    "

You can shorten this a little by referring to the block argument via _1:
'tags'.yield_self { _1.ljust([8, _1.length].max) }
#=> "tags    "


While I agree with @Stefan's Answer, specifically the portion that does not use numbered block parameters, because I think the named parameter adds to readability and understanding, there is another option which is to use BasicObject#instance_eval

instance_eval {|obj| block } → obj
Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables and private methods.

So in this case your code can be changed to:
'tags'.instance_eval { ljust([8, length].max) }
#=> "tags    "
# As the docs mention you can also pass a string
'tags'.instance_eval("ljust([8,length].max)")
#=> "tags    "

Due to the fact that the execution context is the receiver, the implicit self would be 'tags', although this object is also yielded as a block parameter so you could obtain the same semantics as the other answer.
'tags'.instance_eval { |str| str.ljust([8, str.length].max) }

Since this method accepts a block it also adheres to block standards as they relate to variable scoping so the following works equally.
padding_length = 8 
'tags'.instance_eval { ljust([padding_length, length].max) }
#=> "tags    "

But as noted by Stefan because blocks are a closure and Ruby's lookup prefers local variables over over methods, when no receiver or method invocation syntax is used, you will need to keep this in mind or preferentially use self as the explicit reciever e.g.
padding_length = 8
length = 12
'tags'.instance_eval { ljust([padding_length, length].max) }
#=> "tags        "
'tags'.instance_eval { ljust([padding_length, self.length].max) }
#=> "tags    "

Please be advised that due to the execution context both instance variables and private methods are available and as such this should be taken into consideration when using this method.
Alternatively, and under the same caveats, you can use instance_exec as well. instance_exec provides the added advantage of passing arguments to be yielded to the block for example:
pad_me = ->(padding_length: 8) { ljust([padding_length, self.length].max) }

'tags'.instance_exec(&pad_me)
#=> "tags    "
'tags'.instance_exec(padding_length: 10, &pad_me)
#=> "tags      "


Somehow I knew both you and @Stefan would be all over this question...

When working with instance_eval / instance_exec, keep in mind that the block is a closure and existing local variables that were set beforehand might mask method invocations. For example, having a preceding length = 8 results in 'tags'.instance_eval { length } returning 8 which might not be obvious. You'd have to use self.length or length() in such case to enforce a method invocation.

Why the Originally-Posted Code Doesn't Work
Stefan provided a great practical answer, but didn't really explain why your current code doesn't work. I'll try to do that to supplement his answer with a bit more understanding of how Ruby works. Based on your example, but with a few minor changes such as renaming object.length to obj.length to avoid confusion with the Object class, you described your problematic code as similar to the following:
# +obj+ refers to the string 'tags'
calculated_length = 2
'tags'.ljust([calculated_length, obj.length].max)

This actually raises a Ruby Exception object:

undefined local variable or method `obj'

This happens because in Ruby, almost everything is a method and almost everything is an expression that returns a value. Since you haven't defined anything to call the String#length method on when you call obj.length this causes a NameError exception because obj is undefined at that point in the evaluation of the code. Depending on how you are defining your calculated length, you may have the same issues there, too, but the current exception is raised before you would see that error.
Ways to Fix the "Undefined Variable" Problem
In the code above, if you replace the second argument to String#ljust (i.e. obj.length) with a defined variable or a pre-calculated Integer value then it will work without errors. For example:
# pass an Integer literal as your second argument
calculated_length = 2 + 1
"tags".ljust([calculated_length, 8].max)
#=> "tags    "

# give the :length method something defined as a receiver
calculated_length = 32 / 4
str = "tags"
str.ljust([calculated_length, str.length].max)
#=> "tags    "

These both work fine. It's not really a scope probem; it's just that when you use a String literal the argument list you're using has no way to determine that the original literal is intended to be the receiver when you invoke String#length in your argument list.
By either setting the String as a variable that will be defined inside the argument list or by passing the literal as an argument to a block using Kernel#yield_self (or its alias Kernel#then) you can get around this fundamental syntax issue. for example:
# pass your String literal into a block; technically,
# "tags" passes _itself_ into the block as positional
# block argument +_1+
"tags".then { _1.ljust([8, _1.length].max) }
#=> "tags    "

# assign your values to an instance or local variable
# so they won't be undefined inside your block or the
# argument lists
calculated_length = 2**3
str = "tags"

# using argument lists
str.ljust [calculated_length, str.length].max
#=> "tags    "

# block form using same values defined above
"tags".then { _1.ljust [calculated_length, str.length].max }
#=> "tags    "

Refactoring Further: Less Elegance, More Testability
Also, even though it may seem less elegant, you might consider refactoring for readability and testability rather than compactness. Readability is certainly in the eye of the beholder, but testability often gets a big boost from having well-named intermediate and explanatory variables that can be inspected in a step-wise fashion. For example, I would personally find the following one-line method easier to read and debug than the current Array expression even without the YARD documentation. There are also other ways to write this method even more explicitly if you like.
# A one-line "endless method" tested with Ruby 3.4.4.
#
# @note The YARD documentation for this method and
#   its examples is 29 lines, longer than the single
#   line required to define it!
#
# The method name may seem oddly truncated, but makes
# more sense when you verbalize it as "custom padded
# string". Likewise, using more traditional signature
# like `custom_padded_str str` would be duplicative.
# Naming things in a way that communicates your
# authorial intent is always a hard problem!
#
# @example a String variable with default padding
#   str = "foo bar"
#   custom_padded str
#   #=> "foo bar "
# @example a String var with custom padding expression
#   str = "foo bar"
#   custom_padded str, 4**2
#    #=> "foo bar         "
# @example passing just String and Integer literals
#   custom_padded "string literal", 20
#   #=> "string literal      "
#
# @param str [String] required positional argument
# @param padding [Integer] a pre-calculated value
#   for padding the String; defaults to +8+
# @return [String] a left-justified padded string
def custom_padded(str, padding=8) = str.ljust(padding)

I consider this semantically clearer and easier to write unit tests for, but you may not. My main reason for this type of refactoring is that embedding evaluated expressions into a call to String#ljust, and especially the use of Array#max inside the method call, are part of what obscures the original error you experienced. Any code can have bugs, but having step-wise code where values and individual lines can be debugged with either Kernel#puts or the debug gem when you run into problems can save a lot of heartache.
Even if you dislike my particular take on how to refactor the code, moving some of your logic out of the method call and into explanatory variables would have helped identify the root cause faster in my opinion. Your mileage with coding styles may certainly vary.

You could extend String class by adding a custom method:
class String
  def my_ljust(length)
    ljust([length, self.length].max)
  end
end

'tags'.my_ljust(8)

But not sure it makes much sense because ljust method won't cut the string length already.

Monkey-patching core classes can be risky. If you're going to do this, you should probably at least ensure that it's either a refinement or an instance method. You probably won't clobber anything with :my_ljust for this use case, but you can't actually be sure unless you first determine if String.respond_to? :my_ljust before (re-)defining it. The answer is practical and is a good quick fix, but monkey-patching core classes always has non-zero risk in my own experience.
